# Performance decrease after many inserts from DevForce Client

Tags: devforce

We have a DevForce client console application that does data migration. It reads an old db and writes the data into the DeveFore Server that is hosted via IIS. In the beginning the app runs very fast but after a couple of thousend records it crawls almost to a halt. It is the command Manager.SaveChangesAsync() that then takes then several seconds to complete (for about 30 records each).

We have tryed Manager.Clear(), even newing up a new Manager that replaces the old one, but nothing improves the situation. Something in the DevForce Client makes the save take longer and longer after a couple of thousend records are added.

From the memory side everything looks fine. It is not that the client or the server use more and more memory - the saves just take forever.

Any input would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of DevForce are you using?

Generally a gradual degradation in performance is memory-related, but since that doesn't appear to be the problem here it's hard to say.  How are you issuing the SaveChangesAsync calls - do you have multiple concurrent saves?  Is it possible a save has errored out and is then causing downstream problems?  Do you perform any expensive validation during a save?  Any other information you can provide to help narrow this down?